# What's the best slideshow viewer for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: javascript, picture-library

After working with the Picture Library Slideshow Web Part for a while, I'm unhappy with it's display. On a blank wiki page, it looks fine, but when you start adding other web parts on the page, it just doesn't display well. I see a lot of unnecessary whitespace above and below and the scroll buttons are "below the fold."

The javascript examples I see on the web are 2007 solutions that seem to rely on changing SharePoitn 2007 specific mark up.

Do you have a great example of a Javascript Slideshow web part for SharePoint 2010? I'm not interested in Silverlight because my consumers don't all have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript/jQuery is today the standard way to build slideshows. I agree with AlexSSE that Nivo Slider is a great choice, but there are tons of others - and new ones popping up every month.

If you have an example for SharePoint 2007, it shouldn't be too hard to adapt it to SharePoint 2010. For example, if it is based on Web services or RSS, it'll work the same on both platforms.

Comment: The examples that I liked that used 2007 were doing manipulation of a list view web part by hard coded css styles that don't exist in 2010. Is there no example of a jQuery slider hooked up to a web service picture library that improves on the OOTB web part?

Comment: Could you share a link? It's not that the styles don't exist in SP2010, they just have different names.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Creating-your-own-Content-Slider-for-SharePoint.aspx) is an article I wrote for nothingbutsharepoint.com on creating your own content slider.  It's based off an announcements list, but the library handling the rotation works for images too.  Something similar could be constructed, and it works on both 2007 and 2010, not being reliant on the SharePoint DOM.

I'm sure the crux of the issue is the nonstandard file sizes of the pictures and not entirely a SharePoint slide show issue, generally speaking.

Comment: I give you a plus 1 for contributing something close that has it's own value, but it's not really what I'm looking for because it's not a slideshow viewer.

Comment: Bah sorry, I totally glazed over slide show, I was thinking images not powerpoint, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using different jQuery plugins? Take a look at [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

Comment: or http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/ - another jQuery plugin (There are tons of similar plugins out there)

Comment: +1 for Nivo Slider

Comment: Thanks for the jQuery plugin suggestions. If I roll my own, they will help. But those are just jQuery plugins, they aren't web parts and by themseleves don't replace the ootb web part I refer to in the question.

Comment: No they don't. Are you using publishing pages or web part page?Try to use the publishing one and adjust space as you need by custom div layouts